# Azure - Adding an App Service SLOT to APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm adding a new API in Azure API Management Service (gateway) from an existing Azure resource (App Service).

Surprisingly, when I browse all app services, there is no option to choose a deployment slot (dev/app-service), and only the default slot (app-service) is available.

Is there a way to link a App Service slot with APIM other than manually adding HTTP endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to **`Link your Azure Web app Slot to APIM`** is by visiting that *Slot and attaching APIM instance and API to it*:-

**`My Azure Web App slot:-`**

[image]

***`Visit the Slot > API > API Management > Select your APIM instance > Your API > LINK API:-`***

[image]

[image]